# how can i import other module class in visual studio code

Tags: python, class, visual-studio-code, import

my problem is i use visual studio code to write python program ,
but i cannot import other module class(Ui_Form) to current module

this is my current module:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from HR_System.view.main_window import Ui_Form

    class MainWindow(QWidget,Ui_Form):
        def __init__(self):
            QWidget.__init__(self)
            self.setupUi(self)
    
    app = QApplication([])
    window=QWidget()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

the original modul(path:HR_System.view.main_window):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1024, 700)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Terminal")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irVD8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eNlm.png)

json launch:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-msedge",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

why is no module ?? i use python 3.8.6

Comment: Can you post the screenshot about your project's folder structure and error?

Comment: i added 2 screenshots can u check pleas

Answer (score 0):

In **launch.json**, add

```
    "env": {
        "PYTHONPATH":"${workspaceFolder}"
    },
```

Then **Run without Debugging**, you can see the winform is shown:

[image]

Comment: thank you but i want the window hold same design and features in Ui_Form class form main_window module :(

Comment: You can open another issue about python development. If my answer helps solve your original question about importing modules, please [mark](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) it for more people with similar questions to reach it.